# Is there a way to find all Rolify roles scoped to a resource

Tags: rolify

If I've got a number of roles which can all be scoped to the same resource (can be :administrator or :staff of an individual Agency instance), is there a single method which will return all of those roles, if I have a user and an agency?

Specifically-

```
User.rb
  rolify

Agency.rb
  resourcify # roles of :agent and :administrator exist on this resource
```

I'm looking for a single-method equivalent of `@user.has_roles_for? @agency` which will return true if the user has a role which points at that agency.  Currently, I'm using `(@user.roles & @agency.roles).eql? []` to check if this is the case, but hopefully there's a cleaner way to show it.

Comment: Could your provide an example of exactly what you want?

Comment: @EstevanVedovelli Added in an edit to better describe my goal

Comment: Currently there is no method that returns what you need. The closest is `Agency.find_roles(nil, user)`, which will return the roles for the resource class.

Comment: Ah well.  Put it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently there is no method that returns what you need. The closest is `Agency.find_roles(nil, user)`, which will return the roles for the resource class.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question after 9 years as, I have stumbled upon the same requirement.

`User.roles` returns an `ActiveRecord` object.

In your example you can therefore call

```rb
@user = User.first
@agency = Agency.first

@user.roles.where(resource: @agency)
```

This returns all the roles of the User object scoped to the given Agency.